# expect more lines matching cr/lf

Tags: expect

trying all possibilities of matching 2 lines captured.
It replies `Already in Advanced mode\x0d\x0aCX_CM>` (I translate specials to hex)
and I try `expect "Already in Advanced mode*C?_CM>"` or `expect "Already in Advanced mode\r\nC?_CM>"` or `expect "Already in Advanced mode\r*C?_CM>"` or whatever else, but no one worked. It end in timeout or mismatch of next send.
Any idea, please?
Thanks Jiri

Added debug:

```
send: sending "SECURE ON\r" to { exp5 }
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "password?\[y/n]:"? no
"password:"? no
"Already in Advanced mode\r\nC?_CM>"? no
SECURE ON
Already in Advanced mode
CX_CM>
expect: does "SECURE ON\r\nAlready in Advanced mode\r\nCX_CM>" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "password?\[y/n]:"? no
"password:"? no
"Already in Advanced mode\r\nC?_CM>"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Already in Advanced mode\r\nCX_CM>"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "SECURE ON\r\nAlready in Advanced mode\r\nCX_CM>"
send: sending "PASSWORD ADMIN\r" to { exp5 }
invalid command name "ADMIN"
    while executing
"ADMIN"
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I stupid, it was few lines below, not escaping [.

```
Changed user \\\[ADMIN] password\r\nC?_CM>
```